# C++ objects share attribute - use pointer or reference

Tags: c++, pointers, object, reference

I want to write a class where some of the objects share a common attribute.

In the end I have created somthing that looks like this:
I have created a class A with a vector of objects B and a object C where each object b saves a reference to c.

```
Class A{
  vector<B> v_b;
  C c;
}

Class B{
  C& c;
}
```

The objects in the vector "v_b" should be able to change "c" (add a value to a vector stored in c) If one object adds a value, it should also be added to all other objets in the vector "v_b". This was the main thougt, why I wanted to "share" this object.

In the end it does not really work the way I want it to work and I need to rethink this problem.

My question now is, is it better to save C as a reference or to use pointers?

In the end, I really only need the vector "v_b", I'm not interested in the class A, I have used A only to create a couple of A objects with "v_b" vectors and than I used a getter to get all "v_b" and save them in a common vector.

Example:

```
vector<b> v;
{
  A a1;
  a1.add_b_to_vector(B b1); // b1 and b2 should share a common c
  a1.add_b_to_vector(B b2);
  A a2;
  a2.add_b_to_vector(B b3); // b3 and b4 should share a common c
  a2.add_b_to_vector(B b4);
  v.push_back(a1.get_vector_of_bs()); //lets assume push_back would work
  v.push_back(a2.get_vector_of_bs());
}
// do something with v
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want a pointer, not a reference. A reference makes it impossible to use the assignment operator in a natural fashion:

```
class B
{
public:
    B(const B&) = default;
    B& operator=(const B&) = default;

private:
    C& c;
};

void assign(B& b1, const B& b2)
{
    b1 = b2; // this will not work! operator= is deleted
}
```

You cannot rebind a reference, so if `&(b1.c) != &(b2.c)` in the above example, it is impossible to assign `b2` to `b1`.

The correct solution would be to do something like this:

```
class B
{
public:
    B(C& _c) : c{ &_c } {}

    B(const B&) = default;
    B& operator=(const B&) = default;

private:
    C* c;
};
```

This ensures that you can never end up with a null pointer value for `c` while still allowing you to use the assignment operator in a natural way.

As an aside, this is an example of the [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). You might find the [Boost.Flyweight](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html) library useful to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and useful links, I will try that out!